# jQuery get index among matched element type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is there a better way to detect an element's index by type than what I've got? `<span>`s are interspaced by `<em>`s. Various tinkering suggests to me I'm still an ignorant programmer.

```
target.parent('td').children('span').index(target)
```

HTML Looks like this. I want to get the index 3 for 'time', which the above does. `target.index('span')` returns 27, so I dunno.

```
<td>
    <span>once</span>
    <em> </em>
    <span>upon</span>
    <em> </em>
    <span>a</span>
    <em> </em>
    <span>time</span>
    <em> </em>
    <span>in</span>
    <em> </em>
    <span>Mexico</span>
    <em> </em>
</td>
```

Comment: What do you mean `by type` ? Do you mean by selector? Without more explanation "a better way" is very general. Depending on your markup and your JavaScript this could very well be the best way.

Comment: Sorry, self-taught, don't know the proper jargon. 'By type' I mean index of the element among 'span' siblings, ignoring 'ems', 'divs', etc.

Comment: To be honest I actually don't think there is a better way. Is there a reason you need a better way? Is something not working as expected?

Comment: @zfrisch This is actually way costlier/verbose than it could be.

Comment: I don't know, elegance? Shaving microseconds? It's probably just OCD-related that something could be better. Problem is I'm too much of an amateur to know which things make a difference to performance and which don't. Poster below suggests a shortened form should work, so I don't know...

Comment: @Jeto maybe? There's no markup so we'd have to speculate on the what the DOM looks like. If you have to search upwards from target(whatever that is) and then search through that nodes children, it's going to be this expensive regardless. We'd need more info.

Comment: @zfrisch Well we know that a `<td>` element is the immediate parent of `target`, and that this `<td>`'s children contain `<span>`s, therefore these spans are siblings of `target`. The answer below should work exactly the same, but I may be missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: my previous answer was wrong, as I misunderstood the docs (even though I believe it would be a lot more logical the way I thought it worked), sorry about that!

### Updated answer

`target.siblings('span').addBack().index(target)` should be a tiny bit more efficient, as it won't traverse the DOM back and forth.

It takes the siblings spans + itself and returns its position among it.

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  var target = $('#time');
  
  var position = target.siblings('span').addBack().index(target);
  console.log(position);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<td>
  <span>before span 1</span>
  <span>before span 2</span>
  <span>before span 3</span>
  <span>before span 4</span>
</td>
<td>
    <span>once</span>
    <em> </em>
    <span>upon</span>
    <em> </em>
    <span>a</span>
    <em> </em>
    <span id="time">time</span>
    <em> </em>
    <span>in</span>
    <em> </em>
    <span>Mexico</span>
    <em> </em>
</td>
</table>
```

### Previous (incorrect) answer

Just `target.index('span')` ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-selector)) should do it, unless I misunderstood.

Demo:

```js
$(function() {
  console.log($('#span1').index('span'));
  console.log($('#span2').index('span'));
  console.log($('#span3').index('span'));
  console.log($('#span4').index('span'));
  console.log($('#span5').index('span'));
  console.log($('#span6').index('span'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td>
  <span id="span1">once</span>
  <em> </em>
  <span id="span2">upon</span>
  <em> </em>
  <span id="span3">a</span>
  <em> </em>
  <span id="span4">time</span>
  <em> </em>
  <span id="span5">in</span>
  <em> </em>
  <span id="span6">Mexico</span>
  <em> </em>
</td>
```

Comment: Doing that gives me a result 4 times as high as it should be. I've not been able to find the source if it is something that's interfering with normal functioning.

Comment: Please post your HTML then, at least a sample where this happens. The code from this answer does give you the position of the given elements among all the other sibling spans (aka, ignoring the non-spans).

Comment: Can I get back to you in the morning? The evening beers are making me foggy and I can't find where to private message...thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @MikeyB :) sure mate. No need to PM though, just edit in in your opening post, so everyone can see it. Gnight then.

Comment: I've updated with some html, it's puzzling to me where these other numbers are coming from as they don't seem to relate to anything. Obviously there's more going on in my code but I can't see what would affect the simple function.

Comment: @MikeyB I've updated my answer with your HTML and the results are still fine. Something else must be happening, maybe you can try and post a snippet as well and play around with it until you can reproduce your own case?

Comment: @MikeyB Actually, I think I understand what's going on. Let me get back to you with an edited answer (maybe in a couple hours, gotta run for now).

Comment: @MikeyB Updated my answer, the original one was actually invalid. Not sure this is enough of an improvement, I'll let you be the judge :)

Comment: Cool, I'll give that to you. It basically answers my question as it provides a neater/quicker solution. I wasn't aware of addBack() and yes had tried querying siblings but obviously it aint a sibling of itself. Now why your original answer leads to traversing the DOM back and forth I have no idea and frankly I don't care :)